# Smoothing Core Graphics curves

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer

I'm trying to create a circular loading bar and want to use Core Graphics instead of masking images to create the effect. However, I'm not getting the fidelity that I was hoping for:[image]

No matter what have I've tried, the jaggies seem pretty bad. Antialiasing is on and I've already tried turning the "flatness" down to .1 on the `CGContextRef`. The image is from the (Retina) simulator, it looks *slightly* better on a device but still isn't that great.

Drawing code, within a subclass of CALayer:

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {    
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);

    CGFloat delta = toRadians(360 * percent);

    CGFloat innerRadius = 69.5;
    CGFloat outerRadius = innerRadius + 12;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithRed:99/256.0 green:183/256.0 blue:70/256.0 alpha:.5].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithRed:99/256.0 green:183/256.0 blue:70/256.0 alpha:10.0].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathAddRelativeArc(path, NULL, center.x, center.y, innerRadius, -(M_PI / 2), delta);
    CGPathAddRelativeArc(path, NULL, center.x, center.y, outerRadius, delta - (M_PI / 2), -delta);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, center.x, center.y-innerRadius);

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Is this the best Core Graphics can do or am I missing something?

Comment: Considering that your image has clearly been scaled by 2 in each dimension, and you took the image from the Retina simulator, I would say there's a problem with the transform of your layer, or one of its parents.  Are you creating `ctx` in some other method or is the framework passing it to you?  What is the output of `NSLog("%@", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription])`?

Comment: The context is given to me by the CALayer. [Here](http://pastebin.com/0Gjkxh2a) is the output of the `recursiveDescription`. `KDGoalBar` is the UIControl subclass this is being placed in and `KDGoalBarPercentLayer` is where the actual drawing is being done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found out my specific problem. Since I was creating a `CALayer` (to add as a sublayer) the `contentScale` was not automatically getting set to a Retina display. This solves it:

```
percentLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Thanks Rob, for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: I wish I could +10 this.

Comment: scaling, is the pitfall for newbie like me who preview the draw code in non-retina screen and see jagged edge when deploy in retina screen. Your "scale" word immediately remind me I am drawing in non-retina context and expect it will be exactly the same in retina context. +1 for you.